# How do we write an arrow above a letter?

Tags: arrows

I am using `\downarrow` to insert an arrow above a letter. 
For example, using `b\downarrow` creates the downarrow next to b.But I want to position it above b.

Edit:
I intend to use these arrows in equations, where I have to add the description of parameters in the equations. I would like to use these uparrows or downarrows and add a description

Could someone help?

Comment: Does `\vec b` give you what you want? Or `\overrightarrow{b}` or `\overleftarrow{b}`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `\overset` macro, which takes two arguments:

```
$\overset{\downarrow}{b}$
```

The `\overset` macro is provided by the `amsmath` package. Note that `\overset` directives can be nested. A full MWE (mininmum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\overset{\downarrow}{b}$ \quad
$\overset{\overset{\text{text}}{\downarrow}}{b}$
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you're going to use this construct repeatedly -- say, to "explain" various items in a formula -- it's useful to set up a dedicated macro (called, say, `\explain`) to simplify matters. Writing `\explain{text}{b}` beats writing `\overset{\overset{\mathclap{\text{text}}}{\downarrow}}{b}`, doesn't it?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathclap macro
\newcommand\explain[2]{\overset{\overset{\mathclap{\text{#1}}}{\downarrow}}{#2}}

\begin{document}
$\overset{\overset{\text{text}}{\downarrow}}{b} \quad \explain{text}{b}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Will these options also allow me to write a text above the arrow? For instance, `A$\xrightarrow{\text{$text$}}$B$` allows me to write text above the arrow.

Comment: @Natasha - Do try out `$\overset{\overset{\text{text}}{\downarrow}}{b}$`. (Note that `\overset` directives can be nested.) I've added this code snippet to my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Replacing the second last line with `\[
A\xrightarrow{\text{a}}\overset{\downarrow}{B}\xrightarrow{\text{a}}C
\]` doesn't seem to work. Have I missed something? I am trying to write A to B to C, downarrow above B.

Comment: Turns out the OP wanted to add descriptions to some terms. Instead of using nested `\overset` I'd use a `\substack`, maybe with a `\mathclap`. This can be easily generalized to `\underset`.

Comment: @campa Still,I would like to know why `\[ A\xrightarrow{\text{a}}\overset{\downarrow}{B}\xrightarrow{\text{a}}C \]` isn't working?

Comment: @Natasha - I experience no problems at all compiling `\[ A\xrightarrow{\text{a}}\overset{\downarrow}{B}\xrightarrow{\text{a}}C \]`. Please be more specific as to what you mean by "isn't working" and/or "doesn't seem to work". *What exactly* isn't "working"?

Comment: The error occurred because I used `\text{a_{n}}`

Comment: @Natasha - `_` is a math-mode command, it is used to initiate subscript mode. It definitely shouldn't occur in the argument of `\text`. (`\text` is a macro to typeset text material in *text mode*.)

Answer (score 5):

There is, also, another possibility using `tikz-cd`. This obviously depends on what you want to achieve in your document. I always give you the same result as you wish. `[column sep=1em,row sep=1em]` it give you the possibility to increase or decrease the size of the arrow.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1em,row sep=1em]
{} \arrow[d] & \mathrm{text} \arrow[d] \\
b & b
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:** It is possible to use also `xy` package. Here there is an example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=1pc@C=1pc{
\scriptscriptstyle{\mathrm{text}}\ar[d] & \scriptstyle{\mathrm{text}} \ar[d] \\
b & b 
}
\end{document}
```

[image]